# error:cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘Pt*’ in assignment

Tags: c++

I am new to the pointer usage and encountered a compiling error gcc

Here is my code:

```
class Pt
{

public:

    int Ph;

};

Pt *Pa;

Pa = new T[N];
for(int i=0;i < N; i++) 
    Pa[i].Ph=0;`
```

and the error message:

```
error: expected type-specifier before ‘T’
error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘Pt*’ in assignment
```

What I am trying to do is to declare a class which contains an `int` which is 0 initially ,and provide a mem space to N of that class.

Thanks for the time reading my questions,any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: `Pa = new T[N];` What's that?

Comment: First of all, it should probably be `Pa = new Pt[N];` second of all, I assume that these are actually code fragments, and not your entire code, because if it's your entire code this simply won't compile.

Comment: Yes these are fragments, I only post the parts related to the class declaration since the error seems comes from it.guess i forget to declare T but couldnt see that from the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Without a user-defined constructor, you can value-initialize an object like so:

```
Pt a = Pt();
```

`a` is an object of type `Pt` with its `int` member set to `0`.

To declare an array, use:

```
Pt* Pa = new Pt[N]();
```

The `N` objects in the array are value-initialized, so the following `for` loop is no longer necessary.

To write C++ code, just do

```
std::vector<Pt> Pa(N);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare any type called `T`; probably you have other errors/warnings before that complain about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes

---

1) `Pa[i]` would hold a pointer to pt. so consider writing `Pa[i]->Ph`

---

2)  What you want to do here is not clear:

```
Pa = new T[N];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Pt
{
  public:
    Pt() : Ph(0)
    { ; }

    int Ph;
};

#define CAPCITY 15U

int main(void)
{
  Pt Pa[CAPACITY];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
  {
      std::cout << "Pa[" << i << "].Ph = " << Pa[i].Ph << endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The initializer list of `class Pt` handles setting the field `Ph` to zero when the class is constructed by the array.

BTW, you don't need to use `new` for each variable instance, unlike other languages.

*I highly recommend using more letters for your class and variable names and try to use something meaningful.  Two letters are faster to type, but if that is your justification, take a keyboarding class.*

Comment: Thx for the advice, the variables actually are not named in 2 letters in the my original codes and I just renamed them with the first 2 letters,guess it's not necessary.